# Adding External Image To Jekyll Blog

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I am trying to add an external image to a post using Jekyll. I have tried various html based approaches e.g.

`<img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauhaus#/media/File:Christian-dell_molitor-office-work-lamp-light.jpg">`

but all I get is an icon rather than the image. Checking through markdown I haven't found anything that gives a solution that works ( I guess because markdown uses 'relative' rather than 'absolute' - am I correct?).

So my question is: can I link to external images from within Jekyll? - if I can - how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Trying a few more ideas to solve the problem I found that I was trying to load the file from the wrong place and it should have been:

`<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Christian-dell_molitor-office-work-lamp-light.jpg">`